# Wireshark captures only 802.11 and LLC

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, wireshark, network-traffic

Last time I used `wireshark` for capturing wifi traffic in monitor mode, it worked well, meaning it captured all the traffic from all protocols I needed: http, tcp, etc. Perhaps, I've changed something in its setting and now it only captures the packets from 802.11 and LLC protocols.

I tried to make it work as I did before by checking different checkboxes in wlan0 window (monitor mode, promiscuous mode) and the same for eth0, but it still does the same: captures only 802.11 and LLC packets.

I run it as `sudo wireshark`.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Last time I used wireshark for capturing wifi traffic in monitor mode, it worked well, meaning it captured all the traffic from all protocols I needed: http, tcp, etc. Perhaps, I've changed something in its setting and now it only captures the packets from 802.11 and LLC protocols.

You probably either changed the settings for the network on which it's sniffing, switching it from an open (unencrypted) network to a protected (encrypted) network (using WEP or WPA/WPA2), changed the *type* of protection (e.g., from WEP to WPA/WPA2), changed the settings in Wireshark not to have the password for the network if it's protected, or changed the type of protection specified for the password for the network if it's protected.

I.e., it's reporting "802.11" or "LLC" packets because it's not decrypting the payload and therefor it's not capable of dissecting the packets beyond the 802.11 header (or LLC header, but that's probably encrypted so it's finding a DSAP that isn't the actual DSAP and therefore the dissection of anything above LLC is wrong).

Comment: I didn't change any settings of the router for sure, in fact, I use many different wifi spots every day. Where are these settings in Wireshark?

Comment: Edit -> Preferences, open up the "Protocols" list in the preferences dialog, select "IEEE 802.11". and see the "Enable decryption" check box (it should be checked) and click the "Edit..." button next to "Decryption keys" to see the decryption keys entered into Wireshark.

Comment: Yes, but what about the decryption keys?  Are there any decryption keys present?  (As I said, click on the "Edit..." button to see them.)

Comment: You get them by getting the password for the network.  See [the Wireshark Wiki page on decrypting 802.11](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) for details.

Comment: actually, there are some networks with a password, but the info at wireshark web site is always unavailable.

Comment: "actually, there are some networks with a password"  Then, to see traffic on those networks, you'll have to supply the password.  "the info at wireshark web site is always unavailable"  The Wireshark Wiki is currently down; I've asked its maintainer about it, but I don't know when it'll be back.

Comment: thanks, but I really didn't get how to supply those keys in case I know the password. And I don't have 2 textboxes "key1" and "key2". Could you please explain?